# Angular js: "this" inside ng-if function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anybody help me with next question:

how can I get access to **"this"** element inside **ng-if.** (in my example classname "**class_to_obtain**" of span element)

http://plnkr.co/edit/0s7PCWN2fJ8sJpFSJssV

HTML

```
<style>

.red
  {
    color:red;
  }

</style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCntr">
      <span class="class_to_obtain" ng-if="test()">Test</span>
    </div>



</body>


<script>

demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope) 
  {
  $scope.test = function()
    {
      alert(this.className);



    }

});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I think, `this` would be global on `null` by default. You can bind function to any predefined object. But I cannot imagine any good reason to get `this` from function defined in `$scope`. You'd better used `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: Does it need to be ng-if? you can easily do it with ng-click

Answer (score 0):

you can use $element. [Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YcnglEObXVrvrJWgdh8R?p=preview)

JS code:

```
<script>

demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope,$element) 
  {
  $scope.test = function()
    {

      var result = document.getElementsByClassName("multi-files");
     // alert(this.className);
      console.log($scope);
 console.log($element.className);



    }

});
</script>
```